# Простейший TCP server на node.js

Tags: node.js, tcp

Пытаюсь создать простейший TCP server (node.js)
Собственно с кодом вроде проблем нет:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '0.0.0.0';
var PORT = 6969;

// Create a server instance, and chain the listen function to it
// The function passed to net.createServer() becomes the event handler for the 'connection' event
// The sock object the callback function receives UNIQUE for each connection
net.createServer(function(sock) {

    // We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
        sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

Проблема в том, что это надо разместить на VPS (Ubuntu 14 (64-bit). Все попытки послать пакет по адресу `x.x.x.x:6969` не дают результата.
Сервер стартую командой `nodejs file.js`. Печатает подтверждение (Server listening on...) и тишина.

Comment: Указанный порт доступен из вне? Пробовали отправлять запросы tcp серверу с той же машины через telnet?

Comment: Приветствую. Этот вопрос по администрированию и требует знаний настроек сервера. Лучше всего обратиться к службу поддержки хостинга.

Comment: Да проблема в сервере. Php script отправляет сообщения без проблем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6969 -j ACCEPT
```

решило проблему