# Клиент не подключается к серверу на NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

На локалке все прекрасно работает, клиент подключается к серверу, а уже на vds выдает ошибку

> GET http://domain.ru:5665/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LEzVbkH net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

На vds сервер запускается, выводит, что слушает порт `5665`.

Сам коннект клиента:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://domain.ru:5665');
socket.on('connect',function(){
  socket.on('getConn', function(data) {
    // some code
  });
});
```

С чем это может быть связано? Гугл не помог.

Comment: Порт 5665 точно доступен из вне?

Comment: А как это проверить?

Comment: `telnet domain.ru 5665`

Comment: @DmitriySimushev `Unable to connect to remote host`. Я так понимаю, недоступен. Как можно открыть доступ?

Comment: Зависит от того, что за ОС вы используете на сервере. В linux смотрите в сторону `iptables`

Comment: Может быть полезно http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506622/182771

Comment: Ок, спасибо за информацию. Уже смогу сам найти и устранить проблему.